# Word replacement using regex if the target word is not a part of another word

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on regex expression for a word to be replaced if it is a standalone word and not a part of another word. For example the word "thing". If it is `something`, the substring "thing" should be ignored there, but if a word "thing" is preceded with a special character such as a dot or a bracket, I want it captured. Also I want the word captured if there is a bracket, dot, or comma (or any other non-alphanumeric character is there) after it.

In the string

> Something is a `thing`, and one more thingy and (`thing` and more `thing`

In the sentence above I highlighted the 3 words to be marked for replacement.  I used the following Regex

```
\bthing\b
```

I tried out the above sentence on regex101.com and using this regex expression only the first word gotten highlighted. I understand that my regex would not capture `(thing` but I thought it would capture the last word in the sentence so that there would be at least 2 occurrences.

Can someone please help me modify my regex expression to capture all 3 occurences in the sentence above?

Comment: why can't you do this using the `string.Replace` function along with .Contains, and IndexOf methods.. als ocan you show us what you have actually tried thus far so we can see what you are doing or not doing in regards to using Regex..?

Comment: @MethodMan `string.Replace` would also replace the "thing" in "Something" and "thingy".

Comment: OP doesn't want to replace 'thingy', only the exact word 'thing'. Regex doesn't seem like a bad option here.

Comment: It seems like your confusion may be coming from trying to use a javascript regex tool for a C# regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you code this in C# and use the 'Matches' method, it should match multiple times.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\bthing\\b");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(
    "Something is a thing, and one more thingy and (thing and more thing"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were likely using the javascript regex, which returns after the first match is found.  If you add the modifier `g` in the second box on regex101.com, it will find all matches.

This site is better for C# regex testing: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: where do i add the `g`? On my regex?

Comment: on regex101.com, it's the second box.  In a javascript regex, you would use `/\bthing\b/g`

Comment: C# will match all by default.

Comment: looking at @russ's answer, maybe you should use `@"\bthing\b"` for clarity in C#.  the link I posted will give you this C# string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand for alphanum `[0-9A-Za-z]` is `[^\W_]`

Using a lookbehind and lookahead you'd get

`(?<![^\W_])thing(?![^\W_])`

Expanded

```
 (?<! [^\W_] )       # Not alphanum behind
 thing               # 'thing'
 (?! [^\W_] )        # Not alphanum ahedad
```

Matches the highlighted text

Something is a `thing`, and one more thingy and (`thing` and more `thing`